# while updating profile photo in my app generating new row for updated profile pic with firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am implementing `Firebase` in my `Swift` app for Chat Functionality And I am fetching recent chat history data and populate in `UITableView` so I am able to populate successfully with below code

**Code**

```
var refDemo: DatabaseReference!
var userrefDemo: DatabaseReference!
var handle: UInt!
var updateHandler: UInt!
```

In side `viewDidLoad()`

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
self.refDemo = Database.database().reference().child("Message").child(uid)
self.userrefDemo = Database.database().reference().child("Users")
```

And in side `viewWillAppear()`

```
    self.handle = refDemo.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    let r_id = snapshot.key
    self.userrefDemo.child(r_id).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot1) in
    let snapid = snapshot1.key
    if let dictonary = snapshot1.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
           let r_user = RecentChat(dictionary: dictonary, id: r_id)
           self.data.append(r_user)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.tblList.reloadData()
            }
     }
   }, withCancel: nil)
 }, withCancel: nil)
```

this is my code for populate in tableview

and when profile pic change I used below code with observer .childChanged but its not work for me here is the code

I put this code inside `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.updateHandler = self.refDemo.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    let key = snapshot.key
    self.userrefDemo.child(key).observe(.childChanged, with: { (snap) in
    let value = snap.value
    print(value) //Here i am getting value which is updated by user like if user update email i got email 
        if let dictonary = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
            let r_user = RecentChat(dictionary: dictonary, id: key)
            if let index = self.data.firstIndex(where: {$0.key_id == key}){
                self.data[index] = r_user
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
                self.tblList.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
            self.tblList.reloadData()
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}, withCancel: nil)
```

but with this code I am not able to update tableview with existing row every time new row created

I referred this code from github

https://gist.github.com/michaelevensen/67661c9fadfe4ba0828af800acffe179

Comment: please someone help me

Comment: try updateChildValues instead of childchanged.

Comment: how to use updateChildValues please tell me